Complemented subspaces of $\mathcal s$
Crossposted from Math Stack Exchange
It is well known that a nuclear Fréchet space $X$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $\mathcal s$ (the space of rapidly decreasing sequences) if and only if it has the properties $DN$ and $\Omega$. Is there any characterisation of the complemented subspaces of $\mathcal s$, that is a characterisation not up to isomorphism? Necessary or sufficient conditions would be welcome too.
By standard arguments (namely, the vanishing of $\text{Ext}^1$), it is easy to see that $X$ closed subspace of $\mathcal s$ is complemented in $s$ iff $X$ has properties $DN$ and $\Omega$ and $s/X$ has property $DN$, but this is not a particularly nice result since $DN$ does not behave nicely with respect to quotients.

More precisely, you ask for a continuous linear left inverse of a given embedding $i:X \to s$ with closed image. That $X$ has DN is automatic.

@JochenWengenroth Yes, exactly. In the particular case I am interested in (that inspired the question) $X$ is actually isomorphic to $s$, so even an example of an uncomplemented subspace of $s$ that is isomorphic to $s$ would be very interesting (assuming it exists of course, which seems reasonable to me but has resisted my attempts so far)

Every quotient $F$ of $s$ without property DN (for example, the space of all scalar sequences) yields an example because, by a theorem of Vogt which is corollary 5.2.10 in my Derived Functors in Functional Analysis, there exists a short exact sequence $0\to s\to s\to F\to 0$ which does not split (since $F$ lacks DN).
